# Where can I find a Declaration of Intention filed in the 1930s in Louisiana?

Tags: 20th-century, naturalization, louisiana

I'm looking for a [Declaration of Intention](http://www.genealogybranches.com/naturalization.html) filed by someone living in Tangipahoa Parish in the 1930s. Where am I most likely to find this document?

See also, *The Free Dictionary*, "[Declaration of Intention](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Declaration+of+intention)"

Comment: Welcome to the site, Judy. We are working together to develop great questions for this new Q&A format. I have edited or proposed edits to your question to aid in clarity, but believe you can make further improvements. Consider adding more details. This would include the name of the person you are searching. If you have identified them in the 1930 census, I would provide that reference. Other helpful information would include why you think they would have filed the Declaration from Tangipahoa Parish. Had they settled there shortly upon arrival, for example?

Answer (score 1):

This article http://blogs.archives.gov/online-public-access/?p=2684 from September 2010 indicates that **National Archives at Fort Worth** holds Federal court naturalization records from  Arkansas, Louisiana, Oklahoma, and Texas. Tangipahoa Parish falls within the Easter District of Louisiana on the Fifth Circuit.

So, if the declaration of intention to seek citizenship was lodged with the Federal Court as would be usual after 1929, that would be the place to start your search.

National Archives and Records Administration
P.O. Box 6216
501 W. Felix, Bldg. 1, Dock 1
Fort Worth, TX 76115

Comment: Thank you for the comment. NARA Fort Worth has checked and cannot find his record. They suggested I check with the parish court, but I didn't think that could be done at that time. The 1930 census indicates he was "Al" while the 1940 census indicates "Pa."

Answer (score 1):

You've checked with NARA Fort Worth and they don't have a record. Try the US Citizenship and Immigration Services (USCIS). Their [Genealogy Program](http://www.uscis.gov/history-and-genealogy/genealogy/genealogy-frequently-asked-questions#About1) holds Naturalization Certificate Files (C-Files) dated from September 27, 1906 to March 31, 1956, which covers the time period you're asking about.

USCIS' page on [Researching Individuals](http://www.uscis.gov/history-and-genealogy/research/individuals/researching-individuals) gives the instructions on how to research a single individual's records, depending on when that person arrived in the US and when naturalized. But the same individual may have multiple files, so they recommend performing an index search first.  This [flowchart](http://www.uscis.gov/genealogy) describes the process.  The FAQ on [Searching the Index](http://www.uscis.gov/history-and-genealogy/genealogy/searching-index) explains why the index is not available for us to search online.

After you have paid the fee for an index search, and you have the correct file number or numbers, you can submit a request for the copy of the records.